# Can select element in devtools but not puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chromium

I'm working with puppeteer. I want to get the node value of a selected element in a textbox . Using dev tools I have copied the selector:

```
  var mySelector = "div.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi.filter-main-values.fmd-values.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop > ul > li.search-choice > span";
```

I can use this to find it in devtools:

[image]

But after running my puppeteer code:

```
  var selectedCountry = await page.evaluate((mySelector) => {return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(mySelector))});
  console.log(selectedCountry);
```

In the vs code debug window, I see:

```
(0) []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the selector to the `evaluate` function properly.

```
var selectedCounty = await page.evaluate((selectedCountySelector) => {

  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectedCountySelector))

}, selectedCountySelector); // <-- pass it here

console.log(selectedCounty);
```

Comment: That worked, Thank you. I'm not a node expert, is this standard practice in node or specific for puppeteer?

Comment: This is just the signature of the puppeteer function. Those are just the arguments you need to pass in, like any other function, @user1592380